# How to show the names of the devolpers on Visual Studio 2019 line of codes?

Tags: visual-studio

I'm using Visual Studio 2019. I can't find where is the option to show the developer name on the updated codes.

Like this.

[image]

Comment: It is not clear what you mean. Can you please elaborate?

Comment: @bolov I've uploaded an image for example. Its hard to elaborate, and hard to search on google. I'm not sure how to ask this in google.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> CodeLens is available in Visual Studio Community edition, however, the
> source control indicators are not available in this edition.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/find-code-changes-and-other-history-with-codelens?view=vs-2019

Comment: It does not show the author's name. It is because I'm using the community edition?

Comment: @RonaldAbellano Yes, the author's name is not displayed in the Community edition.